# Maple V5 to Maple 18 - How to create a list of variables?

Tags: maple

I used Maple V5 back in 92 to write some functions to solve some problems using Groebner basis. Since then I have used Maple for simple calculations and therefore my programming skills are long-forgotten. Most of the functions I wrote and used at that time no longer work and I am trying to go back and update them to the Maple Version I currently have, that is, Maple 18.

Questions:
a) Is there an automatic tool to update old Maple functions?
b) Commands such as `vars := [x.(1 .. n)]`   used to work but not anymore.   The ideia was to create a list with x1,x2,.. xn.  I know that `seq(x[i], i = 1 .. 5)` would create a list with x_1,x_2, ... but it is not exactly the same.
c) Tips and suggestions how to smooth out the process of updating are most welcome.

Thanks

Ed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were some changes to the language between **Maple V Release 5** and **Maple 6**, and the replacement of `.` with `||` was one of those.

Maple 6 (and 7 if I recall) shipped with an additional binary `updtsrc` which could act on Maple source files and make the text replacements. For example, if I start with a plaintext file `var.mpl` containing just this,

```
vars := [x.(1 .. n)];
```

and then apply the shell command `updtsrc var.mpl` I get this output,

```
`.` has been replaced by `||`; see ?||
vars := [x||(1 .. n)];
```

I did that on Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS Linux, using the (redhat) `updtsrc` binary downloaded from the HTTP link for Linux on [this](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/downloads/updtsrc.aspx) page.

If your Maple V sources are in a .mws worksheet file then you might have to export the input to a plaintext file.

I haven't tried in (on a plaintext file, in a DOS window, or Powershell) on MS-Windows (though the zip file from that page did unpack to a `updtsrc.exe` file).

So if you have a great deal of old codes containing language incompatibilities between Maple V and Maple 6 then you could try this route to automate the conversion.

There have been some commands deprecated betwen Maple 6 and Maple 18 (eg, lowercase `vector`) but few further language changes (backwards incompatibilities).

I suggest that you read the help pages in your Maple 18 for the language updates. In particular I suggest you look at the help pages for these help topics (entering these in the Help Brower's Search bar):

```
updtsrc

updates,Maple6,compatibility
```

As for you second example involving `vector`, it is true that `vector` has been deprecated and superceded by the `Vector` command.

But even in MapleV R5 you should not really have been using `op(f)` on vector `f`. More correct would have been `eval(f)` or `evalm(f)`. Eg,

```
f:=vector([-x1^2,x2*u]);

                                            [   2      ]
                                       f := [-x1 , x2 u]

var:=u;

                                            var := u

subs(var=cat(var,0), eval(f));

                                         [   2       ]
                                         [-x1 , x2 u0]
```

Now, suppose you instead use `Vector` in the above. In that case using `op(f)` in that `subs` call will produce the error you cited, because unlike `vector` the `Vector` beast does not have last-name-eval.

```
f:=Vector([-x1^2,x2*u]);

                                               [   2]
                                          f := [-x1 ]
                                               [    ]
                                               [x2 u]

var:=u;

                                            var := u

subs(var=cat(var,0), op(f));
Error, invalid input: subs received 2, which is not valid for
its 2nd argument
```

You could still use `eval(f)` here, but in fact it is not necessary.

```
subs(var=cat(var,0), eval(f));

                                            [   2 ]
                                            [-x1  ]
                                            [     ]
                                            [x2 u0]


subs(var=cat(var,0), f);

                                             [   2 ]
                                             [-x1  ]
                                             [     ]
                                             [x2 u0]
```

Lastly, try to download and install the point-release Maple 18.02 rather than stick with Maple 18.00. You can find that [here](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/downloads/m18_02update.aspx).

Comment: Many thanks.   I have used updtsrc on the code and only a copule messages related to || and <> were issued.  The update code does not work unfortunately.   I will have to go through each and every function to see where the error is.   They used to work flawlessly on Maple V 5.

Comment: One of the old commands, linalg[vector]([op(convert(f,list)),seq(dinvar[i][2..11],i=1..nu)]);,  resulted in [-x1*x2+u0, x1^2-2*x2, [u1, u2, u3, u4, u5, u6, u7, u8, u9, u10]],  I think the intention was [-x1*x2+u0, x1^2-2*x2, u1, u2, u3, u4, u5, u6, u7, u8, u9, u10] but I could not figure out how to achieve that. Any suggestions?

Comment: It's not clear to me whether (or how) this new example's output changed between Maple V and Maple 18. And it's difficult to address without knowing exactly what `f`, `dinvar` and `nu` are. Best would be to cast it as a wholly new post either here or on mapleprimes. If you don't want to bother posting all the code you can set it up as a small standalone bit of code by using the `lprint` command to see exactly what to assign to those names as example setup.

Comment: In the old code there was no need to use op for the second part.  Once I added to op([u1, ...,u10]), the function worked. many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The command that you're looking for is

```
vars:= [x||(1..n)];
```

Maple V 5 was released in 1997. Almost all documented commands available in that release still work today. The current version in '92 was Maple V. The current version today is Maple 2016, not Maple 2018. I'm not aware of any automatic update tool.

Let me know if you need more code translated.

Comment: Thank you very much.  Sorry about the mistakes. Maple V instead of V 5, Maple 18 instead of Maple 2018.  I definitely need more code translated but I am not sure how to send them.  I am afraid the thread will be filled up with small comments for each one of the codes.  What should I do?

Comment: Another example.  f:=vector([-x1^2,x2*u]) and var:=u  then subs(var=cat(var,0),op(f))   The last command won't work anymore: subs received 2, which is not valid for its 2nd argument.

Comment: It may be easier for you to post your questions on www.mapleprimes.com. The sequence of three commands that you give above works fine in current Maple. You must have something else going on. Try **restart**. The **vector** still works, but is deprecated. Use **f:= <-x1^2, x2*u>** instead.

Comment: When using the new Vectors, you shouldn't use **op** with their name.